# Obtaining a continuous segment from sequence

Tags: sql-server

I have sequence *[dbo].[TestSequence]*

```
CREATE SEQUENCE [dbo].[TestSequence] 
AS [int]
START WITH 1
INCREMENT BY 1
MINVALUE -2147483648
MAXVALUE 2147483647
```

This sequence is used by many customers.

Can I guaranteed take continuous segment of numbers from this sequence? I use MS SQL server 2016.

Comment: Your guarantee will be based on how good your code is. How familiar are you with sequences and their limitations? If not very, don't guarantee anyone anything.

Comment: That's what [`sp_sequence_get_range`](https://learn.microsoft.com/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-sequence-get-range-transact-sql) is for.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Thank you!

Comment: Why such a low minimum value when the sequence starts with 1? And really sequential numbers are likely going to have gaps anyway when rows get deleted.

Comment: @JeroenMostert put that in an answer before more people vote to close this perfectly good question.